# Identifying plain backgrounds around segmented instances with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, classification, object-detection

I am trying to write a classification algorithm that will identify images that 1) feature people on 2) a neutral/plain background. The idea is to find images that will be easily 'silhouettable' by human editors. I am *not* trying to actually do the foreground extraction myself.

I am using a combination of object detection (in particular, Mask R-CNN) and OpenCV. Here's what I have so far.

Here's a positive example of the images I am trying to identify:

[image: positive example]

Mask R-CNN will tell me that, yes, there is a person here, and even provide the mask for instance segmentation:

[image: masked image]

Then I can grab the mask and manipulate my image using OpenCV:

```
# just get the first mask
mask = masks[0]
# invert the mask
inverse_mask = np.invert(mask).astype(np.uint8)
# use bitwise_and to extract the background
inverse_masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask=inverse_mask)
```

[image: extracted background]

At this point I have to perform some kind of test on extracted background. And I'm open to ideas! But my first thought was to try detecting any edges in just the masked region.

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im,(5,5),0)
smooth = cv2.addWeighted(blur,1.5,im,-0.5,0)
edges = cv2.Canny(smooth,100,200)
edges_inverse_masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(edges, edges, mask=inverse_mask)
```

[image: mask with edges]

This seems promising, but I am getting the edges around my instance. So, any test on 'edges' will fail as there *are* some edges.

Does my edge detection idea seem like a good one? If so, how can I improve my code so that it works?

Or are there other avenues I should explore?

Comment: can you do a step of dilation once you get the mask  ? so that the small edges get cleared ?

Comment: Are you trying to obtain a mask with the person in white and the background in black?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan should i perform dilation on the masked image or the mask itself?

Comment: @nathancy no, i was able to get the mask fine. what i want is to detect edges in the background (the inverse mask). so, these edges that correspond to the mask are false positives for my use case

Comment: @rexsavior dilate the mask, so that the region of the person is extended over the edges, and it eliminates those extra white dots you get !

Comment: this seems like a good idea. i'm not quite sure i know how best to implement it, but i'll keep at it. so far i haven't been able to adequately dilate the mask -- it leaves behind a few edges.

but perhaps i am not using dilate correctly?

```

kernel_size = 3
kernel = np.ones((kernel_size, kernel_size), np.uint8)
dilate = cv2.dilate(inverse_mask, kernel, iterations=1)
```